# How to install conda without Anaconda or Miniconda installer?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I don’t want to use Anaconda or Miniconda as they install their own version of Python. I need just the conda package manager which I can use with my existing version of Python in existing virtual env. Is there any way to install conda package manager which can work with existing Python installation?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this is not possible:

> Currently supported install methods include the Anaconda installer and the miniconda installer.

From [here](https://pypi.org/project/conda/)

You will either need to install miniconda/anaconda, or use another package manager.

Comment: I have a virtual env with some python libraries already installed in it. Now I want some other Python libraries from conda repositories so I was thinking to use conda package manager to install them in same virtual env.

Comment: @ParagChaudhari no, Conda can only install packages in Conda environments - you can't use Conda to install into other site-packages. BTW, I'd also plug [Miniforge](https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#miniforge) and its variants.

Comment: @ParagChaudhari You should be able to reinstall the libraries from the current env in a new Conda env.

Answer (score 3):

There is a conda-forge alternative to miniconda, https://github.com/conda-forge/miniforge#download. This offers many packages not found with anaconda. You can have multiple versions of Python installed, so find the equivalent version of Python that you have installed and select that with the conda command and then pull all the other packages you need to match that from the anaconda or conda-forge trees. You can't mix conda with any other environment manager (and use of pip is possible but not a good idea), but the conda environment works well.

Comment: The conga-forge replacement for miniconda is called miniforge, but note that there is also an alternative called mambaforge. mamba greatly improves the speed for package resolution for complex installations. Both also add the conga-forge channel to the locations searched for packages, also usually a good thing.